# Change axes within Seaborn figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm relatively new to programming and brand new here, so go easy on me. I have a query within Python that returns weekly revenue, 'stops' (deliveries), and 'pieces' (packages) per week for a particular branch, going back as many weeks as the user requests. I want to print a figure using Seaborn that shows each plot next to each other, but I also want to be able to edit the plots. For instance, I can't figure out how to change the Y axis to read "Revenue" instead of "mean(Revenue)" without making it a separate figure. Same for Stops and Pieces. Trying to change anything on the individual axes doesn't seem to work. Also, how do I add a title to the figure? I have tried and it just seems to ignore my code.

See the code here and the image of what it is currently returning:

```
    customer_rev_df = pd.DataFrame(customer_rev, columns='Week Revenue Pieces Stops'.split()).tail(weeks)
    print(customer_rev_df.set_index('Week'))
    sns.set_style(style='whitegrid')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(16, 6))
    ax1 = sns.factorplot(x='Week', y='Revenue', data=customer_rev_df, ax=axs[0])
    ax2 = sns.factorplot(x='Week', y='Stops', data=customer_rev_df, ax=axs[1])
    ax3 = sns.factorplot(x='Week', y='Pieces', data=customer_rev_df, ax=axs[2])
    fig.show()
```

[Graph as it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEcMl.jpg)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that still doesn't work. It just seems to ignore that code and prints out the figure exactly the same. Still shows mean(Revenue), mean(Stops), mean(Pieces). Any other ideas?

Also, any suggestions as to getting a title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a different label for each plot using `ax.set_ylabel()`

For some sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(0,5), 'B':range(0,5), 'C':range(0,5)})
sns.set_style(style='whitegrid')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
ax1 = axs[0].plot(df.A.values)
ax2 = axs[1].plot(df.B.values)
ax3 = axs[2].plot(df.C.values)

axs[0].set_ylabel('Revenue')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Stops')
axs[2].set_ylabel('Pieces')

axs[0].set_title('Revenue')
axs[1].set_title('Stops')
axs[2].set_title('Pieces')

fig.show()
```

[image]

For your code, you will want:

```
customer_rev_df = pd.DataFrame(customer_rev, columns='Week Revenue Pieces Stops'.split()).tail(weeks)
print(customer_rev_df.set_index('Week'))
sns.set_style(style='whitegrid')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(16, 6))
ax1 = sns.factorplot(x='Week', y='Revenue', data=customer_rev_df, ax=axs[0])
ax2 = sns.factorplot(x='Week', y='Stops', data=customer_rev_df, ax=axs[1])
ax3 = sns.factorplot(x='Week', y='Pieces', data=customer_rev_df, ax=axs[2])

axs[0].set_ylabel('Revenue')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Stops')
axs[2].set_ylabel('Pieces')

axs[0].set_title('Revenue')
axs[1].set_title('Stops')
axs[2].set_title('Pieces')


fig.show()
```

Can also iterate over a list of labels e.g.

```
labels = ['Revenue','Stops','Pieces']
for label, ax in zip(labels, axs):
    ax.set_ylabel(label)
    ax.set_title(label)
```

Comment: @Emac Glad to hear it, you are welcome :) Don't forget to upvote and accept if it solved your issue. Cheers

Comment: @Emac Also, for a "global" title use `plt.suptitle()`